# PHP Show more decimal numbers

Tags: php, input, numbers, decimal

i want to show numbers like this 200,00 when i write them in input.

Like i write 200 and automatically the number changes to 200,00

How can i do this?

```
<?
Value 1 <input type="text" name="value1">
Value 2 <input type="text" name="value2">
?>
<?
$total = $value1 + $value2;
?>
```

`$total` must have ,00 numbers at the end

Comment: are you referring to `.` and not this `,`?

Comment: Use [number_format()](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to format the values when you echo them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function

```
$total = "1279";
echo number_format($total, 2, ',', '.'); // 1.279,00
```

#### Syntax

```
number_format(number, decimal, decimal seperator, thousand seperator)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use number_format to echo the variable on your site.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
number_format($total, 2, ',', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a function called `number_format`

```
echo number_format($total,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
number_format( $total, 2, ',', '' );
```